# Hangouts keyboard not showing (Nexus 7 2013 Android lollipop)

Tags: keyboard, 5.0-lollipop, google-hangouts

I have a Nexus 7 2013 and recently upgraded to Lollipop. I'm having problems with hangouts making it unusable.

When I open a conversation in Hangouts, the keyboard is never available. The text bar at the bottom stays grey (same colour as app background) and never becomes tappable to allow the keyboard to show.

I tried last night clearing the cache on the app and this worked briefly but since re-starting the tablet the problem is back.

This is a huge problem as it is meaning I cant use Hangouts (the main messaging app I use with friends and family) on my device and instead have to hunt for my phone each time.

Does anyone have any experience of this or sensible suggestions?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having the same problem